# Adding two Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, ivalueconverter

I have been playing with wpf lately and got stuck at a point where I would like to use two, binding path values sum as the binding of a third control. I tried using value converter but to no success. Would appreciate if any one can guide me to the right path.

Here is what I have so far:

I have two encoders like

```
  <my3:NVAngle Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Top="610" BindableValueExtended="120" BindableValueRetracted="0" AnimationDuration="2" x:Name="nvAArm3Rotate" BindableValue="0" InvertExtendedTag="False" InvertRetractedTag="False"  />
  <my3:NVAngle Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Top="610" BindableValueExtended="50" BindableValueRetracted="0" AnimationDuration="2" x:Name="nvAArm2Rotate" BindableValue="0" InvertExtendedTag="False" InvertRetractedTag="False"  />
```

and I would like to rotate an image with an angle which is the sum of above two angle encoders. Something like:

```
<Image Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="200" Source="/Images/ExtraInter.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="117" Height="15" RenderTransformOrigin="0.95, 0.5">
   <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform>
                    <RotateTransform.Angle>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BundleArm3Full}">
                            <Binding ElementName="nvABundleArm2Rotate" Path="BindableValue" />
                            <Binding ElementName="nvABundleArm3Rotate" Path="BindableValue" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </RotateTransform.Angle>
                </RotateTransform>
                    <!--120-->
                </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

and my converter is:

```
 public class MultipleBindingAddConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var doubleValues = values.Cast<double>().ToArray();

        var resultSum = doubleValues.Sum().ToString();

        return resultSum;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I still see no rotation of the Image although I can guarantee that the BindableValues are changing. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML. How can you expect anyone to help you without knowing the actual code/XAML you're dealing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  Multibinding with a Converter that does the sum.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource sumConverter}" >
  <Binding Path="FirstValue"/>
  <Binding Path="SecondValue"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: My converter was the problem, was returning string instead of double. Works great now, Thanks!